# How to cancel ScheduledFuture task from another task and end gracefully?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

I am playing with `ScheduledExecutorService`. What I want to do is to start a simple ticker (one tick per second) and schedule another task later (after five seconds) which cancels the first one. And then block the main thread until everything finishes, which should be after both tasks finish (+- five seconds).

This is my code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Runnable tickTask = () -> System.out.println("Tick");
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTickTask = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(tickTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Runnable cancelTask = () -> scheduledTickTask.cancel(true);
executor.schedule(cancelTask, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

The problem which suprises me is that it BLOCKS as if there were still some running tasks. Why? The `cancelTask` should end immediately and the `scheduledTickTask` was just cancelled, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the Javadoc of [`ExecutorService.awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) (emphasis mine):

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution **after a shutdown request**, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

That means you need to call [`shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) first, like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Runnable tickTask = () -> System.out.println("Tick");
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTickTask = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(tickTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Runnable cancelTask = () -> {
    scheduledTickTask.cancel(true);
    executor.shutdown();
};
executor.schedule(cancelTask, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

In your case, the timeout will never happen because you practically set it to "infinity" and the current thread is not interrupted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is a simple note in Javadoc I have missed. Is there any way how to shut scheduler down after the last task is cancelled automatically? Or you would have to keep a counter somewhere and shut down after it equals zero?

Comment: @voho I don't know if this is possible using `ScheduledExecutorService`. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23369952/1743880).